# How to create a jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to get to know how to create a very simple jqGrid just to get used to javascript and jQuery. I have been searching online but unable to find any resources which explain that. so a simple example would be great or a link to a tutorial.

Comment: jqGrid can be used to display local data or it can make ajax requests to fill the grid. It can be used additionally to make modifications on the server of the data displayed. Moreover you can use JSON of XML data as the input. If you use server side data holding you will need to write the server code and probably access to the database. So you will need much more code examples. So you should describe your requirements more exactly. If you just start with jqGrid you can look at the demo page http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html for many live examples with some code templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest gird you can create with jqGrid is probably the one populated by an array. You can find an example [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). But basically all you need is this:

```
var mydata = [
        {id:"1"}
        ];
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
height: 250,
colNames:['Inv No'],
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}

],
caption: "Manipulating Array Data", 
    data: mydata
 });
```

You can find all the information you need in [the jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs).

EDIT:

I fixed the bugs pointed out by Oleg and used the new data parameter. 
Ahmad: You can do this in an included js file or in your html between  tags. You should really look at the examples and look at the source of the demo pages.

Comment: The code `i<=mydata.length` should be changed to `i<mydata.length` and the comma before ']' should be also removed or one more column definition should be added to the `colModel`. Moreover starting with the version 7.2 jqGrid support `data` parameter which work more effective to fill the data (see description of the `data` parameter on the http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). So it would be better to move the definition of the `var mydata` **before** `jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({...});` and include `data: mydata` as the additional jqGrid parameter.

Comment: Thanks! But where do I type that? In HTML?